# Can I replicate the bevel and shadow without a background?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, automation, batch-processing, image-editing

I have about a ton of screen shots that I need to convert to a design that has been used in the past on our sites.

All of the pictures are saved with a white background so that they could see the bevel and shadow effects.  See example below.  (Grey area is just screenshot)

> [image]

I have added it in quotes so you can see the white background.

Is there a way to get the same bevel/shadow without the white background?  I am trying to create a batch process to go through all of our stuff.

Comment: If you save as PNG you can save transparent images. The shadow on an object will then still be visible if placed on a lighter background.

Answer (score 1):

1. Open your image
2. add a layer mask / shrink the image / crop the layer (but keep the image size)
3. add your bevel effect and the shadow
4. Save as a transparent PNG

Bonus: your shadow will be visible over backgrounds of any color, not only white anymore!